# Stack using doubly linked list for the first time in C, with no printing

Tags: c, linked-list, stack

I have implemented my stack using doubly linked list and I don't know why it's not printing, I think it has something to do with the right C syntax or something?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* prev;
    struct Node* next;
} Node;

//---------------------Stack---------------------

typedef struct Stack {
    int size;
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
    int top;
} Stack;

const Stack stack_init = { .size = 0, .head = NULL, .tail = NULL, .top = -1 };

Node* create_node(int elm) {
    Node* node = malloc(sizeof * node);
    if (!node) return node;
    node->data = elm;
    node->prev = NULL;
    node->next = NULL;
    return node;
}

void push(Stack s, int elm) {
    Node* updated_head = create_node(elm);
    if (!s.head) {
        s.head = updated_head;
        s.tail = s.head;
    }
    else {
        updated_head->next = s.head;
        s.head->prev = updated_head;
        s.head = updated_head;
    }
    s.size++;
    s.top = s.head->data;
    // printf("%d ", s.tail->data);
}

int pop(Stack s) {
    Node* node = s.head;
    int elm = node->data;
    s.head = s.head->next;
    if (s.head) {
        s.head->prev = NULL;
        s.top = s.head->data;
    }
    else {
        s.tail = NULL;
        s.top = -1;
    }
    s.size--;
    free(node);
    return elm;
}

int top(Stack s) {
    return s.top;
}

void clear_s(Stack s) {
    while (s.tail)
        pop(s);
}

Stack reverse_s(Stack s) { // iterative
    Stack s2= stack_init;
    while (s.tail) {
        push(s2, pop(s));
    }
    while (s2.tail) {
        push(s, pop(s2));
    }
    return s;
}

int is_empty_s(Stack s) {
    return s.tail == NULL;
}

void print_s(Stack s) {
    Node* trav = s.head;
    while (trav) {
        printf("%d ", trav->data);
        trav = trav->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {

    Stack s1 = stack_init;
    push(s1, 5);
    push(s1, 4);
    push(s1, 3);
    push(s1, 2);
    push(s1, 1);
    print_s(s1);
    
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, the stack is based off my doubly linked list which is functional and working, but the print function when starting from the `head` node doesn't output anything.

Comment: `push()` gets its arguments by value. So it's modifying a copy of `s1`. The functions that modify the stack need to receive a pointer to the stack.

Comment: PS: `reverse_s()` won't be doing what you think it will be doing...

Comment: What if one too many calls to `pop()` occur?

Comment: Right, I forgot the `is_empty_s` check

Comment: When I do the ` if (!is_empty_s(&s)) {` in pop I get warning, why is that?

Comment: "_why is that?_"... If you've now changed the code to pass pointers to the helper functions, the `s` pointer in those functions is a pointer already. You pass that pointer (by value!) to any lower functions WITHOUT taking its address...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C uses call by value which means that `push(s1, 5)` will actually pass a copy of s1 and 5 are to the function.  As you want to mutation you need to pass the address of `s1`.  Copies can be expensive, so even for a non-mutation you may prefer (also for consistency) to pass a pointer to Stack, but mark it `const`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* prev;
    struct Node* next;
} Node;

typedef struct Stack {
    int size;
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
    int top;
} Stack;

const Stack stack_init = { .size = 0, .head = NULL, .tail = NULL, .top = -1 };

Node* create_node(int elm) {
    Node* node = malloc(sizeof * node);
    if (node) {
        node->data = elm;
        node->prev = NULL;
        node->next = NULL;
    }
    return node;
}

void push(Stack *s, int elm) {
    Node* updated_head = create_node(elm);
    if (!s->head) {
        s->head = updated_head;
        s->tail = s->head;
    } else {
        updated_head->next = s->head;
        s->head->prev = updated_head;
        s->head = updated_head;
    }
    s->size++;
    s->top = s->head->data;
}

void print_s(Stack *s) {
    Node* trav = s->head;
    while (trav) {
        printf("%d ", trav->data);
        trav = trav->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    Stack s1 = stack_init;
    push(&s1, 5);
    push(&s1, 4);
    push(&s1, 3);
    push(&s1, 2);
    push(&s1, 1);
    print_s(&s1);
}
```

and the resulting output is:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

As @Fe2O3 points outs out below consider eliminating `int top` from your `struct Stack` as it's redundant with `s->head->data;`.

`int size` is also redundant but takes `O(n)` to compute at run-time so that is a more acceptable choice.  That said, you pay the price for updating size on every mutation, and if you never need it that is pure overhead.  Only if you call it more than once does it make sense to cache the size.  To me that is a hint that caller should be caching the `size` if needed.

Prefer using `for`-loops when applicable.  For instance `print_s()` could be written like this:

```
    for(Node* trav = s->head; trav; trav = trav->next)
        printf("%d%s", trav->data, trav->next ? " " : "\n");    
    }
```

Avoid global values whenever possible.  It is, however, a good call to make it a `const`.  You could replace `stack_init` with a function of the same name.  This hides implementation details which makes you code easier to change.

For a library it's best practice prefix each symbol with a namespace.  In your case perhaps "Stack"?  I prefer snake case to camel case so my preferred prefix would "stack_" and maybe even something more descriptive as a stack is usually either implemented as array or a single linked list.

Comment: In `push()`... `s->top = s->head->data;`  What happens when the value of data doesn't quite line up so conveniently???

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  Can you clarify please?

Comment: Just bothered that `s->top` is a useless duplication of data, opening the door to bad code that uses a value that is incorrect... OP has written an overly complicated implementation involving `size`, `top` and `prev` but not thought through the failure of `reverse_s()` to perform its function... A gentle rebuke is in order, imho...

Comment: Also, how can you modify `reverse_s` regardless of whether it does the job.

Comment: If `malloc()` fails to allocate space, the NULL pointer will be dereferenced, anyway... Too much attention to "double" and not enough attention to KISS, imho... `:-)`

Comment: @Fe2O3 Not sure where the line is between just answering op's question with minimal changes for ease of understanding and rewriting the code to fix every issue we find.  It entirely possible that my answer is not good enough on this, btw.

Comment: Feel free to make any point out any possible fixes possible

Comment: Agreed... Yesterday's "Luhn's Algorithm" is a case in point... Part of the response in cases like this, though, should indicate that "this corrective patch will fix one thing, but will not make the code work flawlessly." That 'middle ground' is composed of shifting sands, to be sure! `:-)`

Comment: Can you show how reverse should be syntactically correct. We have `Stack* reverse_s(Stack *s)`, then I have `while (s->tail)` with a warning under `->`, why?

Comment: @user21078706 Please file a new question.  Notice how I minimized your code to only the problem at hand.  This makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: @AllanWind Here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75447790/second-stack-inside-reverse-function-with-pointers-warning