# second stack inside reverse function with pointers warning

Tags: c

I have the following stack implementation using doubly linked list, and I want to use a second stack inside the reverse function but I get errors. how to do that, let's say I want to return `s2`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* prev;
    struct Node* next;
} Node;

//---------------------Stack---------------------

typedef struct Stack {
    int size;
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
    int top;
} Stack;

const Stack stack_init = { .size = 0, .head = NULL, .tail = NULL, .top = -1 };

Node* create_node(int elm) {
    Node* node = malloc(sizeof * node);
    if (!node) return node;
    node->data = elm;
    node->prev = NULL;
    node->next = NULL;
    return node;
}

int is_empty_s(Stack *s) {
    return s->tail == NULL;
}

void push(Stack *s, int elm) {
    Node* updated_head = create_node(elm);
    if (!s->head) {
        s->head = updated_head;
        s->tail = s->head;
    } else {
        updated_head->next = s->head;
        s->head->prev = updated_head;
        s->head = updated_head;
    }
    s->size++;
    s->top = s->head->data;
}

int pop(Stack *s) {
    if (!is_empty_s(s)) {
        Node* node = s->head;
        int elm = node->data;
        s->head = s->head->next;
        if (s->head) {
            s->head->prev = NULL;
            s->top = s->head->data;
        }
        else {
            s->tail = NULL;
            s->top = -1;
        }
        s->size--;
        free(node);
        return elm;
    }
}

Stack* reverse_s(Stack *s) { // iterative: using another stack, queue
    Stack *s2 = stack_init;
    while (s->tail) {
        push(s2, pop(s));
    }
    return s2;
}

int main() {

    Stack s1 = stack_init;
    // Queue queue1 = queue_init; { .size = 0, .head = NULL, .tail = NULL, .front = -1 };
    push(&s1, 5);
    push(&s1, 4);
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see the reverse function is not yet completed, I am new to C and this syntax I don't know how to handle it.

Comment: "_I get errors_." Which errors do you get when you do what?

Comment: In `reverse_s`: the first argument of `push` is  `Stack*` but you provide a `Stack`.

Comment: Even when I do this: `Stack *s2 = stack_init;` it gives error

Comment: This error `error: incompatible types when initializing type ‘Stack *’ using type ‘Stack’
   77 |     Stack* s2 = stack_init;`

Comment: Post the verbatim error log. Don't make us guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `reverse_s`, `s2` is of type *pointer-to-Stack*. `stack_init` has the structure type *Stack*. The assignment of a `Stack` value to a `Stack *` variable is incompatible.

A few options for `reverse_s`:

Return a `Stack` structure.

```
Stack reverse_s(Stack *s) {
    Stack s2 = stack_init;

    while (s->tail)
        push(&s2, pop(s));

    return s2;
}
```

Return a *pointer-to-Stack*, dynamically allocating memory for the structure.

```
Stack *reverse_s(Stack *s) {
    Stack *s2 = malloc(sizeof *s2);
    *s2 = stack_init;

    while (s->tail)
        push(s2, pop(s));

    return s2;
}
```

Modify the original structure.

```
void reverse_s(Stack *s) {
    Stack s2 = stack_init;

    while (s->tail)
        push(&s2, pop(s));

    memcpy(s, &s2, sizeof *s);
}
```